# Java grab result of variable from button push

Tags: java, random, methods

I have a game where a player moves relative to an amount rolled on a die. EG: Roll a 5, player moves right 5 spaces. My code has a button that when pushed, rolls the die. I want the player to take the result of this and move it corresponding to that. However, my player takes the answer from the diceroll method, not the result of the button. This means when the player moves their person, it rolls the dice again. It's very hard to explain, but hopefully my code can help explain it:

Dice method

```
public int diceRoll()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int  n = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
        System.out.print(n);
        return n;   
    }
```

Dice button

```
diceRollBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                diceRoll();
            }
        });
```

Movement

```
moveC1But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if(playerTurn == true)
                {

                    counterY1 -= 51 * diceRoll();     //As you can see, it's grabbing the method here, I want it to grab the result of the button push
                    firstPanel.repaint();


                }
            }
       });
```

Comment: It sounds like you've already figured out what the issue is. Replace the call with the corresponding button value?

Comment: Yes, I've identified the issue. I'm just not sure how to grab the result. How would I call the button value? Thanks!

Comment: Store it in a variable or send it as an argument (not sure if that's possible with the listener though).

Comment: That's what I mean. I'm really stuck on such a small problem

Comment: How would I store it as a variable? `int diceRollInt = diceRullBut`?

Comment: diceRollBut is an object, so not like that. You could, e.g., set a global variable inside actionPerformed. `latestDice = diceRoll()`. It's not perfect (I'd prefer some solution without a global), but it'd work.

Comment: Let me try that real quick. :)

Comment: Entered this `static int latestDice = diceRoll();` and says that `final` is the only modifier allowed.

Comment: I'm guessing you wrote static inside a method. The variable needs to be declared outside of the method, at the class level.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it inside of public Main and then the action listener. If I wrote it outside of the method, wouldn't it just have the same issue as before. Each time I call it it would return a new roll. Meaning diceRollBut and moveC1But would be different.

Comment: No, you set the value of the variable once, then use that stored information when moving. You might want to read up on variables and scopes while you're at it

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So do I place this outside of a method. Then call it for both diceRollBut and moveC1But? If so how would I call the variable, I can't just call it like a method.

Comment: You have a global variable, accessible by everyone, and you set it once, when rolling the die, then use that variable when you want to use the value of the rolled die. It's quite logical: rolling the die is one operation. Writing down the result is another. You want to roll the die, then read the result later. It sounds like you want to practice some basic java before getting into this. You'd benefit from getting to know the basics a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   static int rollValue;
...

 diceRollBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    rollValue = diceRoll();
                }
            });
```